# Tesseract give wrong results c++

Tags: c++, opencv, character, ocr, tesseract

Hi I am using tesseract 3.02.02 and it give wrong result for very clear images.

Example image:

[image]

code:

```
tesseract::TessBaseAPI *myOCR = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
cout<< myOCR->Version() <<endl;
cout<< getLeptonicaVersion() <<endl;

if (myOCR->Init(NULL, "eng")) {
   qDebug()<< "Could not initialize tesseract";
}

myOCR->SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist","0123456789");
tesseract::PageSegMode pagesegmode = static_cast<tesseract::PageSegMode>(10); // treat the image as a single character
myOCR->SetPageSegMode(pagesegmode);

Mat imm = imread("/home/de/Desktop/0.png");
cvtColor(imm,imm,CV_BGR2GRAY);
threshold(imm, imm, 0, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY | CV_THRESH_OTSU);
imm = ~imm;
common::deleteBorderObjects(&imm);
imm = ~imm;

Pix *pixx = mat8ToPix(&imm);//convert Mat to pix

myOCR->SetImage(pixx);
const char *text1 = myOCR->GetUTF8Text();
```

The result is 1.

I think the image is so clear.

What is the problem here?  Is it about tesseract parameters?

Comment: Every time I see tesseract as a tag I get excited thinking it's about Madeleine L'Engle.

Comment: @Richard It is very sad story

Comment: Check out this short but working tutorial on tesseract : https://youtu.be/2fmzooBKp8A

Answer (score 0):

Tried without  extra processing on my machine. Result was 0.

```
    cvtColor(imm,imm,CV_BGR2GRAY);
    threshold(imm, imm, 0, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY | CV_THRESH_OTSU);
    myOCR->SetImage(imm.data, imm.size().width, imm.size().height,
                    imm.channels(), (int) imm.step1());

    const char *text1 = myOCR->GetUTF8Text();
```

Try to look at your image just before you feed it into tesseract.